# how solve my flutter apk-release showing null

Tags: flutter, dart

I make weather application with weatherapi.com.the application in my emulator work perfectly but when I release it it show me everything is null like that: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DOgr8.png)

Comment: did you add the internet permission in the android manifest?

Answer (score 1):

It seems your app is unable to access internet. In `android/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml`, inside manifest tag, add

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

It is working in debug release because it is already added there. But for release, you need to add it manually.

Comment: you are amazing thank u dud